# How to decode this mysql BLOB?

Tags: mysql

i have read many post related to how to export BLOB entry but my main problem is the output look like this

```
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
```

inside there should be an article with some parameter but im not able to decode it , i though it could be gzinflate (base 64) but was not able to decode it  , thx you to give me some hints

cordially

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what kind of data you expect in the BLOB? Is it a JPEG file? Perhaps a PDF file?

The display you've shown us appears to be a string of hex digits. It's not Base64; that format uses alphabetic characters and a few punctuation marks as well as numbers.

Try using the PHP function [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) (or the equivalent in your host language) on the string to convert it to binary. Or, you can try the MySQL [`UNHEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) to change it to binary.

Either way you'll need to know what to do with it.  If you have access to a Linux style system, save the binary to a file and issue the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command; that command sniffs around in the file to try to figure out what it is.

Comment: thx you for the answer Ollie, i know there is html content and maybe some parameter (im not sure about this) i will try your recommendation

Comment: you anserr where correct , i just uncompress the BLOB and then the result convert from HEX to Text   thanks you very much  (i can 't vote due to low reputation)